Как при оплате получить или передать параметры робокассе?
Подключил оплату через робокассу в связке php/laravel/robokassa. Делал по рекомендации данной статьи. Возникли вопросы:

Как заполнить автоматически реквизитами карту при переходе на платежную страницу, где пользователь вводит реквизиты карты.
Как сформировать платежку с расчетным счетом исходя из совершенной операции платежа по робокассе? Или хотя бы как узнать расчетный счет платильщика при оплате через робокассу?

